# How to Load Data from Oracle Crash Dump File to Oracle Database?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have tried following ways

```
impdp SYSTEM/ABCD DIRECTORY=E:\OracleDM\dumpFile DUMPFILE=dump_Student.DMP  LOGFILE=dump_Student_imp.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DIRECTORY` is not a *real* filesystem path to the `DMP` file - it is an Oracle object. You should create it as `SYS`, grant privileges to user that is going to use it, and then actually *use* that directory.

For example:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> create directory my_dir as 'c:\temp';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read, write on directory my_dir to hr;

Grant succeeded.
```

At the operating system command prompt:

```
impdp hr/hr@xe directory=my_dir dumpfile=...
```

Comment: "SHOW USER" is here just to show who you should be connected to. SYS. The rest shows how to create a directory and use it.

Comment: I cannot able to import dump file even after above steps.I got message completed with 4267 error

Comment: It means that import actually *did* something, but there were (too many) errors. Which ones? You should review the import LOG file and see what's going on.

Comment: Object Grant Failed and ORA-01917

Comment: Grant failed? That's because user doesn't exist (at least, that's what ORA-01917 means). I'd suggest you to read documentation on Data Pump (export and import) in order to move on.